# @Resource injection in JBOSS AS 7 doesn't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, resources, code-injection

**`(UPDATED)`**

I have deployed a web application on jboss-as-7.1.1.Final as standalone, and I have one startup class to initialize as below which works fine:

```
@Startup  
@Singleton  
public class StartupBean {  

    @PostConstruct  
    void init() {  
    EmailSenderService emailSenderService = new EmailSenderService();
    emailSenderService.testMail();
    }
}
```

the problem is in the other class defined as following:

```
@Stateless
public class EmailSenderService {

    @Resource(mappedName="java:jboss/mail/Default")
    private Session mailSession;

    @PostConstruct
    public void testMail(){
        if(mailSession == null){
            System.out.println("NULL"); 
        }
    }
}
```

when starting the application server, the method is called by the startup class, however the mailSession property is not initialized by the container and is null.

I have following configuration in my JBoss standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
    <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
        <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp">
        </smtp-server>
    </mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

Any Idea why mailSession is not initialized by the container?

Although this is a web application, I need to do some initialization prior to HTTP requests, that's why I'm using an @StartUp class and other stuff.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Resource annotation must be used within a bean class. In your case the annotation defined in `EmailSenderService`
it is just ignored by the EJB Container.

[According to ejb 3.1 specification:](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/)

> 16.4.1.1Injection of Simple Environment Entries Using Annotations.
>
> The Bean Provider uses the Resource annotation to annotate a field or method of the **bean class** as a target
> for the injection of a simple environment entry.

Also notice that the field must not be static.

> 16.2.2Annotations for Environment Entries.
>
> The field or method may have any access qualifier (public, private, etc.) but must not be static.

Comment: Dear Gabriel, you mentioned two points; first of all thanks because I didn't know them; I applied them both this way: I defined EmailSenderService class with Stateless annotation to make it a bean class, and I removed the static keyword from the mailSession property, (check updates in the question); I republished my project to JBoss, but still the same; mailSession is null. I even tried PostConstruct for the method testMail() to make sure all the resource injections are done, but it’s null in that call as well. Any other idea?

Comment: The problem is that your are using an instance created by yourself not by the Container:
EmailSenderService emailSenderService = new EmailSenderService()
this is a simple POJO that is not managed by the Container, takes a look at how a bean [works](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giplj.html)

Comment: I checked your link and let the container instantiate the EmailSenderService class by @EJB, and the issue resolved. thanks