# JNDI Lookup with Resource annotation always NULL

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jndi, jersey-3.0

I've got a WebApp with Tomcat 10, Java11 using Jersey3.
I defined a ConnectionPool in my `context.xml` for handling the connection to my OracleDB and now I'm trying to access the DataSource within my controller through a `@Resource` annotation. This should invoke a JNDI-lookup. Unfortunately, I always get a NPE as it seems not to find the resource while running... What am I doing wrong? Or what would the correct mappedName / lookup be?

```java
  @Path("/data")
public class DataController  {

    @Context
    ServletContext context;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/jdbc/myDB") //also tried java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB and mappedName="jdbc/myDB"
    protected DataSource ds; //always null
```

```
<Context name="myapp">
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          name="jdbc/myDB"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl"
          username="xy"
          password="xy"/>
```

According to the tutorials, a ref-link is optional when I define the resource directly in the context.xml.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: if you try to iterate the entire jndi tree, do you see the name of that resource somewhere

Comment: @eis how would I access the jndi tree?

Comment: by iterating values in initialcontext.

Comment: @eis returns an empty list...

Comment: how about tomcat's jmx console? use that and you should be able to browse all entries.

Comment: Did you use `javax.annotation.Resource` or `jakarta.annotation.Resource`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz the jakarta one

Comment: @eis You generally can't iterate JNDI trees.

Comment: @user207421 what? why not? That's what I usually do when I'm having trouble guessing what kind of names there are present. Isn't that what all JNDI tree viewers do?

Answer (score 3):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656530/resource-injection-in-jboss-as-7-doesnt-work) is about jboss, but would seem relevant to you too. It says that according to the specification, Resource annotation to do JNDI lookups would only work with EJBs, so it wouldn't work for your case.

A workaround is to do the programmatic way to see if your datasource is working:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource bean = (DataSource ) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
```

If you can find your datasource you can then try to optimize to avoid "manual" lookup above.

Comment: alright, that seems to work. But calling this everytime I need to get a connection to the DB seems not correct - is there no other way?

Comment: @Remo sure there is, plenty of ways. Like I wrote, the code I wrote was a workaround which you can then try to optimize once you got that going. If you want to use Resource annotation, you'd have to use it in a way specified by the specification - namely using EJBs.

Comment: Hm would there be another way using something like the Resource annotations? I shall not use EJBs though...

Comment: @Remo btw I think Resource annotation should require a bean but possibly not an EJB, so I'm starting to think it should work for your case too, since your jax-rs is regarded as a bean. did you try `@Resource(name = "jdbc/myDB")`  and `@Resource(name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB")`?

Comment: @Remo You need not write the code seen in this Answer every time you need a connection. I suggest you **write this code once, then cache** the resulting `DataSource` object. Every time you need a connection, you retrieve the cached `DataSource` object and call `getConnection`.

Comment: @eis tried both variant of the annotation, did not work.
I'll try to fetch it in the ContextListener and cache it from there. The context is one thing, I can get from everywhere.

Comment: @Remo for `@Resource` to work you probably need `jersey-cdi2-se`.

Comment: @eis jersey-cdi2-se requires a bean.xml, altough I have no EJBs etc.

Comment: @Remo I don't think you meant to comment that to me. But it requires beans.xml, not bean.xml, and that is a requirement of the CDI specification. beans.xml actually is often just empty marker file to enable CDI.